# Swing Java repaint not working using 2 jpanels

Tags: java, swing, 3d, awt, graphics2d

As you can see from the code I am expecting to see a rectangle on DrawingPanel but I am not sure why repaint() method is not working. Any help will be much appreciated. I also tried revalidate method but that is not working either.

Here are my Classes:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Designer extends JFrame {

static JFrame f = new Designer();

JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
PropertyPanel propertyPanel = new PropertyPanel();

 public Designer(){

    Rectangle bounds = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getMaximumWindowBounds();

    splitPane.setTopComponent(propertyPanel);
    splitPane.setBottomComponent(drawingPanel);

    add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(bounds);
    setVisible(true);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("App started...");
 }
}
```

Class for first Jpanel: **PropertyPanel.Java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PropertyPanel extends JPanel {

  private DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();

  public PropertyPanel(){

    JButton addShapesBtn = new JButton("Add");

    addShapesBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawingPanel.addRectangle();
        }
    });
    add(addShapesBtn);
  }

}
```

Class for second Jpanel: **DrawingPanel.Java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{

  private List<Rectangle> squares = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();


 @Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    System.out.println("painting");

    for (Rectangle rect : squares) {
        g2.draw(rect);
    }

}


  public void addRectangle() {

    Rectangle rectx = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
    squares.add(rectx);
    repaint(); <-- this is not working
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repaint works fine. Your problem is that you're calling `addRectangle()` to the **wrong** DrawingPanel instance, not the one that is currently displayed in the GUI. To solve this, pass a reference from the displayed one to the code that needs to call the method.

To see that this is correct, simply search this page for `new DrawingPanel()`. You should see this only **once** in your own code (and your code posted). You see it **twice** meaning you've created two instances of this.

e.g., change this:

```
public class PropertyPanel extends JPanel {   
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();

    public PropertyPanel(){
```

to this:

```
public class PropertyPanel extends JPanel {    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;  // don't create new

    public PropertyPanel(DrawingPanel drawingPanel){
        this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
```

and then pass in the true DrawingPanel into this object on creation:

```
DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
PropertyPanel propertyPanel = new PropertyPanel(drawingPanel);
```

---

Better still: structure your code in a M-V-C way, and use dependency injection to make connections -- but this may be overkill for your simple GUI.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was really helpful.

Comment: @VK321: you're welcome, but does it make sense? Also please see edits to answer.